# JSP session on a website

Tags: jsp

I have a code called

```
User loggeduser = (User)session.getAttribute("loggedUser");
```

I am confused about the use of this code. Can anyone explain the use of this code? Why and how to use on other pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP session objects are used to send one parameter from one jsp page to another.

Suppose you have a form index.html which only asks the user for its username.

```
<html>  
<body>  
<form action="welcome.jsp">  
<input type="text" name="uname">  
<input type="submit" value="go"><br/>  
</form>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Once the user clicks on submit button welcome.jsp page will be loaded

```
<html>  
<body>  
<%   

String name=request.getParameter("uname");  
out.print("Welcome "+name);  

session.setAttribute("user",name);  

<a href="second.jsp">second jsp page</a>  

%>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Now I have another page which wants to know the name of logged in user
for that I can use session.getAttribute like this

```
<html>  
<body>  
<%   

String name=(String)session.getAttribute("user");  
out.print("Hello "+name);  

%>  
</body>  
</html>
```